# not able to pull datetime type from datagridview using C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have this `Datagridview`, where I'm inserting a new row, but the value for the column
`expected_date`, it is getting a null value in the program, when in fact I have typed in `01/01/2099`,
I've tried inserting manually in my code and it works, but when I'm doing something like :

```
dataGridView2[fieldIndex, rowIndex].Value
```

in order to grab `01/01/2099` from the `Datagridview` and use it in my code, it just returns `null` or "" (Empty String).

I'm also just not sure why it's only for the column that uses a date that causes the trouble.

Comment: Could you attach your code?

Comment: What about `dataGridView2[fieldIndex, rowIndex].FormattedValue`?

Comment: please provide your implementation so we can have a better opinion.